# SQLite.swift build error "Module file's minimum deployment target is ios8.3 v8.3"

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite.swift

I have upgraded OS X from 10.9 to 10.10 in order to be able to use Xcode 6.3 - current Version is 6.3 (6D570).

When I created my project with Xcode 6.2 I successfully imported SQLite.swift as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift#installation) and everything was working.

After I upgraded to Xcode 6.3 the project cannot be build - I always get the error:

`Module file's minimum deployment target is ios8.3 v8.3: /Users/d...`

I have tried to set different deployment targets as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307117/error-module-files-minimum-deployment-target-is-ios8-3-v8-3) but nothing helps :(

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your app deployment target 8.3? Have you run **Clean Build Folder…** (hold alt/option when running **Clean**)?

Comment: I tried all the deployment targets from 7.0 to 8.3. Now also tried to hold the alt when running clean - same error

Comment: What if you delete you entire **DerivedData** folder? `rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments - I finally fixed it - the problem was that the deployment target of the imported project was 8.3. After I changed it to 8.0 it worked - that does not however explain the error in case the main project's target is also 8.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem by changing the Deployment Target of the referenced SQLite project to 8.0. If you see iOS Deployment Target 8.3 lower the version and the error shall disappear.

Also clean the project by holding the alt/option key as pointed out by 
 @stephencelis in the comments

Comment: After the change of deployment target, holding alt/option when cleaning the project was very useful for me (without this it didn't work), thank you.