# Using Cocoapods and probably something wrong with Podfile

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am using `Cocoapods` and if I open the generated `xcworkspace` project file then I have two `xcworkspace` files in it. One of them is "pod" file which has all the dependencies, but other project file (my project file) has no files or folders to access(literally nothing, I can only see that the file exists there.) I think the issue might be in my Podfile that I created.

Podfile file:

```
platform :ios, ‘9.1’
use_frameworks!

target ‘XMLElements’ do
    pod 'Fuzi', '~> 0.2.0'
end
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: Not that familiar with the formatting of Podfiles, but is the use of "’" characters okay? Shouldn't they be "'"? Is the target name correct and did you try deleting the line with the pod, then doing the pods install command?

Comment: Okay, I  changed the characters to "'" and now it shows me the my project xcworkspace files and folders, but when I try to import that module "Fuzi" It says this error:

"Module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.1 v9.1 :User/...."

when I delete the line with the pod then it removes all the pod dependencies and then it's says there is no such module as Fuzi.

Comment: Let me write all this down as an answer, as this comment section is too small.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before,
and here is what I did.

Regarding the minimum deployment error, I fixed it by changing the [deployment target version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307117/error-module-files-minimum-deployment-target-is-ios8-3-v8-3).

It says "no such module" because you literally just removed it by deleting the line in the Podfile.
After deleting it, add back in that same pod and try running the command `pod install`. Open the `xcworkspace` project file and see if it does it.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot, now I am able to import the 'Fuzi'! Now I must figure out how to parse with it. :)