# Why Realm's minimum deployment target is ios 9.2?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm database in my ios project
Here https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ wrote that  "Apps using Realm can target: iOS 8 or later"
But when i try to set deployment target to iOS i see that:

```
Module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.2 v9.2: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foodDelivery-cmnxgsvikpzpggdlvsaiegbkeuie/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule
```

Comment: RealmSwift's deployment target is 8.0. It should work. Set project or target's deployment target to 8.0 again, then clean and build. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307117/error-module-files-minimum-deployment-target-is-ios8-3-v8-3

Comment: Thank you! everything is work ! :)